# Write a constructor in class Doctor to initialize the private field doctor_name

Tags: java, constructor

Write a constructor in class Doctor to initialize the private field doctor_name. How can I write this?

```
class Doctor{
    
    public Doctor(private String doc_name){
      
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in your question does not compile. Error is: _Illegal modifier for parameter `doc_name`; only `final` is permitted_ Refer to this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: Welcome here. While the question is perfectly answerable, Stack Overflow is really a poor place for learning the basics of Java (or any programming language). I recommend you rather look at existing code examples (there are thousands out there) and study your text book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example class `Doctor` with a constructor.

```
class Doctor{
    
    private String doc_name;
    
    Doctor(String doc_name){
        this.doc_name = doc_name;
    }
}
```

You can also add a setter and getter to apply encapsulation.

```
class Doctor{
    
    private String doc_name;
    
    Doctor(String doc_name) {
        this.doc_name = doc_name;
    }
    
    public void setDoctorName(String doc_name) {
        this.doc_name = doc_name;
    }
    
    public String getDoctorName() {
        return this.doc_name;
    }
}
```

I've made a simple implementation of the class `Doctor`.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doctor doctor1 = new Doctor("Someone");

        System.out.println(doctor1.getDoctorName());
        doctor1.setDoctorName("Someone Else");
        System.out.println(doctor1.getDoctorName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Someone
Someone Else
```